# How to save scrollback history in byobu?

Tags: byobu

I've had an interesting terminal session in [byobu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu), and I'd like to save the terminal output (commands and all) to a file - how can I do that?

According to the [byobu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/byobu.1.html):

> Ctrl-a ~ - Save the current window's scrollback buffer

This may indeed be doing something, but I've found no indication of where and under what name it might be saved.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Or, you can simply use [Byobu's hotkey](https://askubuntu.com/a/662705/349837) for this:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>

That will take your history and put it into `$BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen`.

Comment: sift-F7 doesn't appear to do anything and the byobu help screen doesn't mention it either - I'm using byobu 5.17 with tmux 1.6 in ubuntu.

Comment: This is awesome, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I'm running byobu 5.74 and that option does appear for me in the help screen and works as described. I'd be surprised if that was not the case given that Dustin is the creator of byobu. :)
Worth mentioning the output is saved at `$BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen` (as noted in the help screen).

Comment: For me it was saved to `/dev/shm/byobu-serg-ucvwj2rJ/printscreen`, where serg is obviously my username

Comment: I know this is an old answer. Anyhow, I experience the same issue: the shift-F7 seems not doing anything (even though the shortcut is present in the help menu). I'm using it on a Ubuntu-16.04 host with byobu version 5.106 & tmux 2.1.

Comment: `Shift`+`F7` was my favorite feature of `byobu`, recently switched from 14.04 to 16.04, it does NOT work the same, instead of opening `vim` it just saves it to `/dev/shm/byobu-myusername-somerandomword/printscreen`

Comment: This partially worked for me (debian unstable), but the buffer only had about 32k lines out of 94k history. @drevicko's answer below worked perfectly though.

Answer (score 41):

An old question still not workably answered for earlier byobu versions, and I hit the need again.

This time I found a workable solution. From `man byobu`:

```
SCROLLBACK, COPY, PASTE MODES

   Each  window  in  Byobu  has  up to 10,000 lines of scrollback history,
   which you can enter and navigate using the alt-pgup and alt-pgdn  keys.
   Exit  this  scrollback mode by hitting enter.  You can also easily copy
   and paste text from scrollback mode.  To do so, enter scrollback  using
   alt-pgup  or  alt-pgdn,  press the spacebar to start highlighting text,
   use up/down/left/right/pgup/pgdn to select the text, and press enter to
   copy  the  text.  You can then paste the text using alt-insert or ctrl-
   a-].
```

1. I hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to enter scrollback mode,
2. <kbd>Space</kbd> to start selecting,
3. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to scroll to the top of the buffer (thanks @GeorgeMarian)

   - If that doesn't work, try this: either with lots of <kbd>Page up</kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd> followed by the largest line number (indicated top right) and <kbd>Page up</kbd> to get to the top of that page,
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy (to byobu's clipboard, not a terminal/system one),
5. then `cat > my-byobu-dump.txt` in the terminal,
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>]</kbd> to paste (again, from byobu's clipboard)
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close the file.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked well for me.

Comment: For step 3, if you want to get to the very top use `gg` (just like vim).

Comment: @GeorgeMarian Do you know if that's from a vim-emulation mode? will people find other behaviours? Seems the default behaviour (at least with byobu 5.17 over tmux 1.6)

Comment: There's no vim-emulation mode in byobu that I know of. There's [vi-like movement commands in scrollback mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413567/is-there-any-way-to-find-something-in-byobu-window), and maybe elsewhere. I just happened to try them, since -- well -- Linux. (I've been using `less` a lot lately, searching and moving around.)

Comment: ok. could it be coming from the underlying multiplex technology (screen or tmux)? Anyway, I've added your suggestion. Many thanks :)

Comment: It guess it could be, but I don't know. I don't remember if I used them back when I was using screen before byobu came out. That said, vi-like movement and some other vi-like things are used in a bunch of Linux applications. (e.g. `less`) You could try switching and see if it makes a difference, but I'd expect byobu to implement the missing functionality if it can. (I.e. tmux back end acting like screen)

Comment: @drevicko if you're still having this problem, I wonder if the following solves it for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/948916/269058

Comment: cat > dump.txt appears to require some magic. cat does not read from the byobu clipboard on my computer

Comment: @Drew do you mean alt+insert etc.. does not paste from the byobu clipboard?? cat without arguments copies from stdin to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

If you're used not to use the F-keys then this might work for you:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>: enter the scrollback mode
- <kbd>Space</kbd> enter the copy mode (optional)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> exit the scrollback or copy mode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>: paste what was copied

Where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is your [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) (default Byobu backend) prefix/escape sequence.

Comment: Also if your terminal program is intercepting the F-keys ;)

Comment: Get your current prefix key with `tmux show-options -g | grep prefix`

Comment: that's something i have to remember! thank you very much! it worked for me, even with the screen backend, not tmux.

Answer (score 3):

Shift + F7 only works as expected if you have the EDITOR environment variable set to an editor *within byobu*. For some reason, in some cases (e.g. for me when connecting through SSH to another computer), setting this variable in `~/.profile` is not enough. One place to set it so that byobu always reads it is in `~/.bashrc`. Copy something like the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Although this is set in ~/.profile, it is set here as well so that in a 
# remote byobu session, Shift+F7 copies the output to a Vim buffer. See:
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/382750/how-to-save-scrollback-history-in-byobu
export EDITOR='vim'
```

Comment: In my case, this didn't help (actually .bashrc is where I set EDITOR anway). As far as I can tell, my terminal emulator (osx default Terminal program) isn't passing on the function keys correctly - probably solvable in Terminal's settings, but the ctrl-A solutions work ok for me.

Comment: @drevicko ah I see, good to know. Well, that's good that we are collecting several workarounds so that hopefully one of them will work for the next person who comes across this issue.

Comment: fyi: [.profile isn't loaded for ssh sessions by default](https://superuser.com/a/564937/101005) - explains what happened here.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to copy the scrollback buffer to the byobu clipboard.

Paste the text into an editor using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd>  or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

(Adjust <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> if you've changed your escape key.)

Comment: I've only a Mac to work from at the moment, and ctrl-a ~ then ctrl-a ] aren't doing anything - I suspect ctrl-a isn't making it to byobu (which is at the other end of an ssh tunnel).. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save the history use <kbd>Shift + F7</kbd> shorcut. Like [@dustin-kirkland](https://askubuntu.com/users/4733/dustin-kirkland) says.

If you prefer to scroll up and down in your terminal, It depends if you use tmux or screen. Examples:

1. Screeen:

   - <kbd>CTRL + a</kbd>: If you use <kbd>[</kbd> then, you enter in scroll mode like [@ikar-pohorský](https://askubuntu.com/users/225797/ikar-pohorsk%C3%BD) says.
2. Tmux:

   - <kbd>ALT + PageUp</kbd>: you scroll up.
   - <kbd>ALT + PageDown</kbd>: you scroll down.

[image: Byobu F1 help]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd> shows me that `capture-pane` and `save-buffer` are the key commands to save scrollback.

```
bind-key    -T root   S-F7             capture-pane -S -32768 ; save-buffer /dev/shm/byobu-asari-JG2wDS8x/printscreen ; delete-buffer ; new-window -n PRINTSCREEN " /dev/shm/byobu-asari-JG2wDS8x/printscreen"
```

When <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> doesn't work for you (e.g. when your terminal software consumes F-key events), try just as help says: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd>, `capture-pane -S -32768 ; save-buffer /path/to/printscreen` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text you wish to save, then press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>
Next, open your favorite text editor. Then paste the content here using <kbd>Control</kbd> +   <kbd>V</kbd> .
Finally save the file in the desired location.

TERMINAL TIP OF THE DAY: When trying to copy something in terminal do it as usual expect use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Control</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>, and paste as usual. For pasting something that is on the clipboard into the terminal use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: its just a simple copy paste scheme, will waste time to copy and then paste . drevicko wants to do it via terminal or automatically saves it somewhere .

Comment: Didn't he say I'd like to save everything to a file? This how he do it.

Comment: No, I believe you'd just get on screen's worth - not the whole (perhaps 10000 line) byobu scrollback history... Note that byobu stores a terminal history that is independent of the terminal app your using.

Comment: If you hold the mouse above the window it will scroll up so that you can highlight the entire thing.

Comment: @drevicko we can save output of commands by using ">" like for saving the output for ls we need to use "ls >file" where file is the text file name, can you just relate it to your question.

Comment: He doesn't want to save the output of one command. He wishes to save the commands and all of the results.

Comment: He will definitely want it to happen automatically. What you are suggesting, IMHO, is a trivial solution.
Just like: "How do I save this picture from the browser?" "Take a screenshot".

Comment: @Cammy_the_block you're missing the "byobu" bit, look it up (a VERY handy thing if you're working on remote servers). It stores terminal sessions that you can disconnect from and later reconnect to. I have 10,000 lines of terminal history that is NOT accessible to the local terminal application. Byobu (and the backend it's using: tmux or screen) have their own set of keyboard driven commands to access that history.

Comment: Is there any reason to keep this post or should I delete it?

Comment: no let it be here , it has discussion bout the question, just remove those pics..

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> will work if you type from 1 to 20 times or more with abracodabra. But the only one command will work without headache to paste text from buffer to terminal or file is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>. Byobu is GPLv3 software, authored and maintained by Dustin Kirkland.