# Is there any way to find something in byobu window?

Tags: byobu

Is there a way to find an expression (<kbd>ctrl-f</kbd> like command) inside a byobu window?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Press the <kbd>F7</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to enter `byobu` [scrollback mode](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/byobu.1.html#scrollback,%20copy,%20paste%20modes). This allows you to navigate past output using `vi` like commands. Here is a quick list of movement commands:

```
h - Move the cursor left by one character
j - Move the cursor down by one line
k - Move the cursor up by one line
l - Move the cursor right by one character
0 - Move to the beginning of the current line
$ - Move to the end of the current line
G - Moves to the specified line (defaults to the end of the buffer)
ctrl + b - Page up
ctrl + f - Page down

/ - Search forward
? - Search backward

n - Moves to the next match, either forward or backward
N - Moves to the previous match, either forward or backward
```